# hive list records which do not match in other table

Tags: hive

```
Reg                      Global
ID | uom                 ID  | uom    
------------------           ----------------
1  | kg                   1  | kg
1  | gm                   1  | gm
1  | ml                   3  | pl
3  | pl
```

Required Output :
r_glob

```
ID | reg    | glob   
------------------  
1  | ml      | null
```

Tried query:

```
SELECT TA.id,  TB.UOM  
FROM TB
LEFT JOIN TA
ON TB.id=TA.id  
WHERE  TA.id like '8' 
GROUP BY TA.id ,  TB.UOM;
```

Output: 
r_glob

```
ID | reg        
------------------  
1  | kg  
1  | gm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left outer join and check for null values in columns from table Global.

```
select Reg.ID, Reg.uom as reg, Global.uom as glob
from Reg
left outer join Global on Reg.ID = Global.ID and Reg.uom = Global.uom
where Global.ID is null
```

Comment: Next I want to try for all uom from reg and null value for uom which do not exist on global :                                                                                     
 ID | reg     | global   
------------------  
1  | kg  | kg
1  | gm | kg                                                                                                       
1  | ml  | null                                                                                      
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok i just posted a new question.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900122/hive-get-list-of-non-existing-and-existing-data