# hive get list of non existing and existing data

Tags: hive, impala

Two tables :

```
Reg                      Global
ID | uom                 ID  | uom    
------------------           ----------------
1  | kg                   1  | kg
1  | gm                   1  | gm
1  | ml                   3  | pl
3  | pl
```

Desired output:

```
ID | reg    | glob   
------------------  
1  | kg      | kg
1  | gm      | gm
1  | ml      | null
3  | pl      | pl
```

Query tried:

```
SELECT reg.id,  reg.UOM  ,glob.uom
FROM reg
LEFT JOIN global glob
ON reg.id=reg.id  and reg.uom = glob.uom
WHERE  glob.uom is null and reg.id =1
```

Output:

```
reg.id | reg.uom | glob.uom 
1      | ml      | null
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the where clause.Just the left outer join will get you the results

```
select Reg.ID, Reg.uom as reg, Global.uom as glob
from Reg
left outer join Global on Reg.ID = Global.ID and Reg.uom = Global.uom
```

Comment: Thanks for both editing the question to HTML and also answering. I got the desired output.